# Cannot cmake mirall because Could NOT find Qt5Keychain (missing: QTKEYCHAIN_LIBRARY)

Tags: qt, qt5, cmake, owncloud-client

I am trying to compile [Mirall](http://github.com/owncloud/mirall) on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Here is the command I am using:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" ../mirall       -DCSYNC_BUILD_PATH=/home/jnbdz/Projects/ownCloudDesktop/ocsync-build       -DCSYNC_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/jnbdz/Projects/ownCloudDesktop/ocsync/src
```

Here is the result:

```
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2

  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2

  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works

  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info

  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done

  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++

  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works

  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

  -- Found Qt5 core, checking for further dependencies...

  -- Using Qt 5!

  -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 

  -- checking for module 'neon'

  --   found neon, version 0.30.0

  -- Found Neon: /usr/lib/libneon.so  

  -- neon-config executable: /usr/bin/neon-config

  -- libneon has not been compiled with LFS support, rely on OS

  CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
```

Could NOT find Qt5Keychain (missing: QTKEYCHAIN_LIBRARY)

```
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 
      (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)

```
  cmake/modules/FindQt5Keychain.cmake:30 (find_package_handle_standard_args)

  CMakeLists.txt:106 (find_package)



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

  See also "/home/jnbdz/Projects/ownCloudDesktop/mirall-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

So I tried installing manually QT5Keychain. By downloading from this page: 
http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtkeychain/.

These two packages: libqt5keychain0_0.3.0-2_i386.deb, and qt5keychain-dev_0.3.0-2_i386.deb.

Then again it sends me the same error.

I also tried to search:

```
sudo find / -name qtkeychain.dylib
sudo find / -name qt5keychain.dylib
```

But did not find anything.

I also tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5keychain-dev
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
qt5keychain-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgcrypt11-dev libgnutls-dev libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libp11-kit-dev
  libtasn1-6-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 119 not upgraded.
```

So it seems everything is install... So I have no idea why it is still complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first of all download libqt5keychain and qtkeychain-dev packages in order to resume mirall compilation.

Use the wget command for each of these urls (it depends on your system architecture):

```
wget http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtkeychain/libqt5keychain0_0.3.0-2_amd64.deb  
wget http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtkeychain/qtkeychain-dev_0.1.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then, install with:

```
dpkg -i qt5keychain-dev_0.3.0-2_amd64.deb libqt5keychain0_0.3.0-2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I tried and did not work. I was told to try this: -DBUILD_WITH_QT4=On In the cmake. But did not change much.